# How to create a template for a wooden photo FRAME to support different types of patterns and styles in PS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

To explain it further How can I create a skeleton or a mould of a photo-frame which would receive a small image of the frame style/pattern as input and convert it into a full rectangular frame with a image placeholder in the middle?

In this way I will be able to create different frame styles of different sizes quickly with a more professional looking output. As of now I am doing this work manually which is timetaking and not so sleek-looking.

On Graphicsriver I saw a lot of PSDs available but in them the frame style has to stay the same and there is not a single template where there is a placeholder for the frame style. Hope I am easy to understand.

Here's what I mean.
[image]

I had tried to ask something similar previously and the solution I got was pretty effective and I have been following that path ever since but still I think there's even a better way do this. 
Any help will be deeply appreciated.

What are the best programs to achieve this. (I love PS.)

Comment: This can't be done with Photoshop. You can easily accomplish this with Pattern Brushes in Adobe Illustrator however.

Comment: If there's any chance that you'll be using the frames in a website: http://imageframer.joonas.me _( If anyone feels like this is ruthless advertising, I have no issues to delete this comment )_

Comment: @Joonas Hey brother, this is amazing. But I would like ask you something. What was your purpose behind building such a tool? I mean I think people don't really make programs to do such trivial tasks. And plz check your mail.

Comment: Dave, I'm not sure what part you mean. I like to make things that make life easier, even if just a little bit. This could have been done without javascript, but it brings a level of easiness since you can tag multiple images easily with a class, instead of copying multiple elements around each image you want to frame. If you were to build this from scratch, a beginner couldn't do it, but with this jquery plugin you just need to copy and paste stuff around and BAM! Your image(s) are surrounded by frames. ( The frames are flexible and can be attached to images of any size ).

Comment: Technically it's a script, not a program. People definitely make the most trivial scripts if it helps even a little bit. - I checked my mail, nothing?